# Statsmodel weird behaviour

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, quantile-regression

I am using statsmodels in python to perform quantile regression. I am running quantile 99 and quantile 1 to see the extremes quantile of my distribution.

```
from statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression import QuantReg
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd

iris = pd.DataFrame(load_iris()['data'])

y = iris[0]
x = iris.iloc[:, [1, 2, 3]]

qt = QuantReg(y, x)
res99 = qt.fit(q=.99)
res01 = qt.fit(q=.01)
print('Quantile 99 description')
print(res99.predict(x).describe())
print('--------------------')
print('Quantile 01 description')
print(res01.predict(x).describe())
print('--------------------')
print('Target description')
print(y.describe())
```

The output is

```
Quantile 99 description
count    150.000000
mean       6.713570
std        1.092909
min        3.972447
25%        5.798665
50%        6.745737
75%        7.447919
max        9.906085
dtype: float64
--------------------
Quantile 01 description
count    150.000000
mean       5.196659
std        0.811265
min        3.110156
25%        4.555466
50%        5.270011
75%        5.777980
max        7.588576
dtype: float64
--------------------
Target description
count    150.000000
mean       5.843333
std        0.828066
min        4.300000
25%        5.100000
50%        5.800000
75%        6.400000
max        7.900000
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

That is, the distributions of the percentile 1, the target, and the percentile 99 are not supper different. Is this expected or am I missing something?

Comment: you can look at a plot. The target doesn't have a lot of spread. Also, you didn't include a constant in the regressors X

Comment: Does the intercept need to be included manually in statsmodels?

Comment: yes, unless you use the formula interface.